# Decrypt PGP from CSV files and output to another CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, encryption, gpgpu, pgp

I have some CSV files that are saved daily and have data that is encrypted using PGP.

I would like to get the CSV data, decrypt it and then save it to an unencrypted CSV file.

I have the encrypted private key and also the password.
The CSV file is called "COC.csv" and PGP content on CSV is like:

[image: PGP content]

I managed to get the CSV data for a variable, but I was unable to decrypt and save it later.

```
# Import CSV file from path
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\guilh\Downloads\Encrypt\COC.csv | out-string

# Check data read from csv variable
#$csv | Format-Table
```

It is my first time using PGP, is it possible to do this using PowerShell or should I use another method?

Comment: Would this help you out ? `https://4sysops.com/archives/encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-powershell-and-pgp/`

Comment: @MyICQ I tried that, but it seems like it only decrypt a file, how do I decrypt a message inside my CSV file and output the decrypted message?